# can not connect to Xserver while running python file using pyQT4 via ubuntu service

Tags: linux, pyqt4, ubuntu-18.04, xserver

I am trying to execute python file which uses PyQT4

I am running below service file

```
[Unit]
Description = Test
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart = /usr/bin/python3 /home/nvidia/main
Restart=on-abort

[Install]
WantedBy =multi-user.target
```

this file is located under `/lib/systemd/system/test.service` and I am starting this service by `systemctl start Test`

but starting of this service results in an error tagged `cannot connect to X Server, failed with result exit-code`

I am using the script

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#################################################################################################################################################

# Author          = Rucha
# Version         = V 2.0.3
# Class           = PR01 OOP
# Module          = pyqt4
# Date            = Jan 02 2021

#################################################################################################################################################
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

######################################################################################################################################

class MainWindow:

    def __init__(self):
        self.vbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()

    def Title(self,Window,Name):
        Window.setWindowTitle(Name)

    
    def window(self):

        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        w = QtGui.QWidget()

        w.setGeometry(800,800,500,500)

        self.Title(w,"Test")          
        
        w.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    
MainWindow1 = MainWindow()
MainWindow1.window()
```

Comment: What does the python script do? Does it really need the graphics server (X11) to run? Can you provide us its code, or at least a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: yes, I have added my script to my question @musicamante

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[Unit]
Description = Test
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment="DISPLAY=:0"
Environment="XAUTHORITY=/home/nvidia/.Xauthority"
ExecStart = /usr/bin/python /home/nvidia/main
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy =graphical.target
```

I successfully executed GUI using `systemd` service using the above directive values

Answer (score 0):

Commonly a service dont have the same environment than a normal user who is able to login/start the X environment.
Therefore i guess `DISPLAY` is not set.
Try this in your service file but make sure it will start after X is already running...

```
ExecStart = env -i DISPLAY=:0.0 /usr/bin/python3 /home/nvidia/main
```

Example - User root try running something on X - with and without `DISPLAY`

```
#kcalc
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display 
Could not connect to any X display.
#env -i DISPLAY=:0.0 kcalc
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
```

You can check this in an XTerm with and/or without `DISPLAY` variable.

Comment: ExecStart = env -i DISPLAY=:0.0 /usr/bin/python3 /home/nvidia/main
modifying to this line results an Exec format error, Xserver is already running for root

Comment: Mh, so try it with X service is not running - Is there any case the script (not the service) is running errorless? - I change running or running not with ```init 2``` ( single user without X ) and ```init 5``` ( multiuser with X )

Comment: yes all the cases before main qt window instruction are running. I have checked for single user with and without X and multi user with and without X

Comment: I also tried by disabling access control for xhost